# How to override plugins?

Tags: extjs

Basically, I want to override `'Ext.ux.TabCloseMenu'` plugin. I plan to add more items to this component and to do localization, because it is not done by default. I try to override it like this:

```
Ext.define('CustomTabCloseMenu',{
    extend:'Ext.ux.TabCloseMenu',
    alias: 'plugin.customtabclosemenu',
    ...
});
```

And this is how I add this plugin to a tabpanel:

```
...
plugins:[Ext.create('CustomTabCloseMenu',{})]
...
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
plugins: 'customtabclosemenu'
```

or

```
plugins: {
     xclass: 'CustomTabCloseMenu'
}
```

?